# Suspend or disable @MessageDriven processing - EJB 3.1 MDB

Tags: java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, websphere-8

I am not sure how to phrase my question correctly.

Below is the background.

I have an EAR proejct which contains a Web project and an ejb project.   The EJB project contains multiple MDBs and I have to add one more MDB to it for a new queue.   All of the project code has been added to source control, so I will be retrieving the code from source control to create my RAD 9.0 project to add the new MDB.

When I add the application to the WAS 8.5 server, it complains about the Queue / ActSpec JNDI not being defined for existing MDBs, because it is processing the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml and also processing the @MessageDriven annotations from the existing MDBs.

So my question is - Is it possible to suspend or disable the processing for existing MDBs without making temporary code changes to comment out the @MessageDriven annotation in all existing MDBs and / or commenting out the activation spec definition from ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml  or  on the other side without having to define all the Queues and Activation spec defintions for the other MDBs?

I am using Websphere 8.5 with RAD 9.0 and MDB 3.1.

Please let me know, if I need to clarify anything more.